# Authorizing users on Rails 4 with CanCan based one roles in a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, cancan

I'm using Rails 4.0.0, ruby 2.0.0p247, and CanCan 1.6.10.

**How do I authorize users with CanCan based on their role in a join table (has_many :through)?**

I have 3 models: `User`, `Group`, and `GroupUser`.

Users and Groups are associated as `has_many` through the GroupUser table. Each GroupUser also has a `role` field, which can be 'editor' or 'owner.' One group can have multiple Users, each with different roles. Also, a User can have roles in multiple Groups.

I have the app setup with CanCan abilities, but instead of limiting access to only users with the correct role, **it is authorizing *everybody***.

**The models** are setup as follows. Also, notice that Group has a method to return a list of its owners.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :groups, through: :group_users
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :users, through: :group_users

  def owners
    User.find(self.group_users.where(role: 'owner').map(&:user_id))
  end
end

class GroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

**The CanCan ability.** Notice that it uses the `owners` method on Group.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    can :update, Group do |group|
      group.owners.include?(user)
    end

  end
end
```

**The View** is as follows. Here, users who shouldn't be able to see the link are still seeing it.

```
<ul class="groups">
    <% @groups.each do |group| %>
        <li>
            <p><%= group.name %></p>
            <% if can? :update, Group %>
                <%= link_to "Edit", edit_group_path(group) %>
            <% end %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Finally, the **Controller action** for the view is:

```
def index
  @groups = current_user.groups
end
```

. . .
One interesting thing is that even though it doesn't work during actual use, the following unit test passes:

```
test 'user can only update groups they own' do
  ability_one = Ability.new(users(:one)) # Owner
  ability_two = Ability.new(users(:two)) # Not-owner

  assert ability_one.can?(:update, groups(:one))
  assert ability_two.cannot?(:update, groups(:two))
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should make `cancan` work with a real object here, passing the actual `group` object to the `can?` method instead of the `Group` class:

In the view:

```
<% if can? :update, group %>
```

Instead of:

```
<% if can? :update, Group %>
```

This way you will ask `cancan` if `current_user` is able to `:update` the actual `group`. Since no ability has been set for operations on the generic `Group` object, the second condition will always be true.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. I spent so much time looking at the [checking abilities wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Checking-Abilities) on the cancan docs, but still missed this: "Important: If a block or hash of conditions exist they will be ignored when checking on a class, and it will return true".  Thanks for your answer.